# How to avoid Visual C++ Redistributable LARGE file installing?

Tags: c++-cli, clr, visual-studio-2017, vcredist

I want to deploy a C++/CLI application on Windows 7 32bit clients. I have built it using Visual Studio 2017 and I noticed my project needs Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable.

My executable file is less than 1 megabytes and the MSVCR dependency is 13 megabytes, which is really huge for this app.

Is there any way I can reduce this amount of size?

Comment: Are those the actual redist packages or the debug version of those? Because that makes a big difference.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I mean the one located here to download: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: Can you build a statically linked version of your project?

Comment: @RichardCritten C++/CLI applications can not be linked statically because of .NET dependencies.

Comment: A word of advice: abandon C++/CLI language and explore alternatives.

Comment: @Ron why? I am able to create fast working applications that support forms designer.

Comment: C++/CLI is meant for interop scenarios between managed and unmanaged code. Using it to develop winforms apps is more of a PITA than anything else and you'd be better off using C# if you don't need to access lots of C or C++ functions. Anyway, see if you can compile with `/clr:pure` - I *think* you don't need the redistributable if you do but I'm not sure. Otherwise, you're pretty much stuck with the redistributable. IIRC its license forbids you from redistributing anything else than the whole package, even if you need a subset.

Comment: You think the 13MB C++ redist is bad, but you forgot to count 140MB of .NET runtime...   C++/CLI has heavy dependencies, there's no avoiding that when you choose a managed platform.

Comment: @BenVoigt The .NET runtime is pre-installed on Windows.

Comment: @Matin: Visual Studio 2017's compilers require a newer .NET than the one pre-installed on Windows 7 and 8.x  Unlike C# and VB.NET, the C++/CLI compilers do not support targeting older runtimes, every compiler is locked to a particular minimum runtime version (Visual Studio does provide some help in using older compilers)

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution but I don't know if it is fine or not.

I can compile my C++/CLI code with Visual Studio 2010 toolkit. So I would need C++ Redistributable 2010 for it.

And instead of installing the whole package I can copy msvcr80.dll and msvcp80.dll next to my executable file, which are less than 1 megabyte size together.