# Are there smaller Visual Studio 2015 C++ Redistributable (vcredist_x86.exe) than 14 MB?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, nsis, vcredist

I have a Windows x86 32 bit desktop application built using Visual Studio 2015 written in C and C++ using the MFC framework for the User Interface. For the installer I am using NSIS compiler with an NSIS script to generate the installation .exe used to install the application which is composed of some 10 different components, .exes and .dlls that are created by the build.

My desktop application is a point of sale application that runs under 32 bit or 64 bit versions of POSReady 7 (Windows 7) as well as Windows 10 and Windows 10 IoT Enterprise (not Windows IoT Core) on Intel x86/x64 compatible CPUs.

When I changed from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2015, I was struck by the larger size of the installation executable, from a size of roughly 8 MB to a size of 16 MB. The size difference seems to be due to the Visual Studio 2015 C++ Redistributable that I am including in the desktop application installer.

The NSIS script has the following lines:

```
# The location of the Visual Studio 2005 C++ Runtime Redistributable depends on the version of
# Windows being used to build the application. Beginning with Windows 7 there are now two different
# folder hierarchies for installed programs.
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\1033\vcredist_x86.exe"

ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\vcredist_x86.exe" /q:a /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qb!"'   #dialog with no cancel
```

When I compile the desktop application with Visual Studio 2015 and run the NSIS script with the `File` directive containing the `vcredist_x86.exe` commented out, the size of the resulting installer is 2,220 KB. When I uncomment the `File` directive containing the `vcredist_x86.exe`, the size of the resulting installer is 16,140 KB.

Looking in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\1033` I see three different redistributables: `vcredist_arm.exe` size 2,639 KB, `vcredist_x64.exe` size 14,957 KB, and `vcredist_x86.exe` size 14,130 KB.

Is there a different Visual Studio 2015 redistributable that is smaller than 14 MB?

Or is there a different method I can use to provide `vcredist_x86.exe` where I do not need to include it within my application installer? A different method would need to be as automatic as the current solution which installs the application components then starts up the Visual Studio 2015 redistributable installer.

**Notes**

1. This post has an answer of including specific Visual Studio DLLs into the components list for the installer.  [How to avoid Visual C++ Redistributable LARGE file installing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108166/how-to-avoid-visual-c-redistributable-large-file-installing)

   That would not seem to be a viable alternative due to copyright issues.
2. Here are links to Microsoft documentation [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=vs-2019) as well as [Determining Which DLLS to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019) which includes an alternative of using merge modules as discussed in [Redistributing Components By Using Merge Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-components-by-using-merge-modules?view=vs-2019). However the page on merge modules says:

   > We recommend that you not use merge modules except when you don't have
   > to service your application and you don't have dependencies on more
   > than one version of the DLLs. Merge modules for different versions of
   > the same DLL cannot be included in one installer, and merge modules
   > make it difficult to service DLLs independently of your application.
   > Instead, we recommend that you install a Visual C++ Redistributable
   > Package.

Comment: most people wont need it so you could detect whether its already installed and download it when it isn't rather than including it in the installer

Comment: @AlanBirtles My application, a point of sale application, could be used with POSReady 7 as well as Windows 10 and Windows 10 IoT Enterprise. Would those already have the Visual Studio 2015 run time installed?

Comment: Windows 10 i think does

Comment: Win10 definitely does, but be careful -- the installed version must be at least as recent as the exact runtime version you link against (I've discovered with VS2019 that they have a nasty habit of breaking ABI compatibility with point releases -- the CRT remains backwards compatible, but an .exe/.dll linked against a newer CRT will not run with an older CRT).

Comment: If internet access at installation time can be assumed, you can go with an online install of `https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe` if the installed version is not recent enough. The version can be checked at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\X86\Version` (without the WOW bit if your installer is a 32-bit .exe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you may provide the required DLLs with your application rather than the installer. Another option is to go for static linking.

These approaches will result in a much smaller overall size, but the dependencies will never be updated for fixes unless you do so. This may be a deal breaker or not depending on the situation.

Comment: What I'm understanding from your post is that I could pick specific required DLLS and include those within my installer. However if I do that then should there be an update to the DLLs since the DLLs are part of my installer then those would not be updated which may lead to security issues? I suppose the same concern would be if I used static linking as well? I suppose there may be a large number of managed components in the VS 2015 installer which are not being used by a native C/C++ application?

Comment: The downside of static linking is that you can't allocate a resource in one DLL/EXE and have it released in another.  Because every DLL/EXE is using it's own c-runtime state  Applies to both memory allocations and file handles.

Comment: @selbie if DLLs are being used then there probably wont be much of a size saving anyway

Comment: @RichardChambers Exactly. The same concern applies, yes. The final size will depend on how much of the stuff you use from the redist, but yeah, the size can be way smaller than 16 MB (for instance, less than 1 MB). As for what comes in the redist nowadays, no idea, sorry.

Comment: If you use the VCREDIST, it is centrally serviced through Windows Update. If you use side-by-side app-local or static linking, the app has to be updated to service any issues. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=vs-2019)